# LXDE change battery and network icons

Tags: lxde, theme

I'm running on Debian LXDE and I'm trying to make the system look a little nicer. I installed the Numix Theme and everything is okay, except for the network and battery indicators, that aren't themed. Here is a screenshot of the system:

[image]

I'm aware that the battery indicator isn't an icon, as pointed in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77957/lxde-change-battery-icon-in-the-panel), but the suggested solution (installing gnome power manager and adding it to the autostart) didn't work for me, as it did nothing.

Is there a way for me to get themed icons there to unify the visuals of my system?